# How to perform an action when a filtered collection changes

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 connected lists that need to work a bit like cascading dropdown lists, that is, selecting an item in the first list filters the second which filters the third.

To achieve this I am using angular filters like so:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <h3>Categories</h3>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cat in model.categories" 
            ng-click="selectCategory(cat)" 
            ng-class="{ active: cat === selectedCategory }">{{ cat }}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Sub Categories</h3>    
    <ul>
        <li 
            ng-repeat="cat in model.subCategories | filter: { parent:selectedCategory }"
            ng-click="selectSubCategory(cat)" 
            ng-class="{ active: cat.name === selectedSubCategory }">{{ cat.name }}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Products</h3>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="product in model.products | filter:{ category:selectedSubCategory }">{{ product.name }}</li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

When the top level category changes (`selectCategory`) I need to ensure that the first sub category is also selected:

```
$scope.selectCategory = function (cat) {
    $scope.selectedCategory = cat;

    // how to select the first sub category?
};
```

Since setting `$scope.selectedCategory` updates the filtered sub categories, is there anyway I can be notified when the filtered collection changes so I can select the first item (`$scope.selectSubCategory`)?

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/dWqhV/

Answer (score 0):

You could [set up a watcher](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch) on `$scope.selectedCategory` and [manually run `$filter`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24filter) to get the first sub-category.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I opted for just performing the filtering in my controller and binding to a "filtered" object on my `$scope`. When the primary category changed we re-filter the subcategories and select the first item:

```
$scope.selectCategory = function (cat) {
    $scope.model.selectedCategory = cat;

    var filtered = $scope.getSubCategoriesOf(cat);
    $scope.model.filteredSubCategories = filtered;
    $scope.selectSubCategory(filtered[0]);
}


$scope.getSubCategoriesOf = function (cat) {
    return $filter('filter')($scope.model.subCategories, { parent: cat }, true);
}
```